# If a family has two children, what is the probability that at least one is a boy?

Tags: probability

If a family has two children, what is the probability that at least one is a boy, assuming there are only two sexes?

One way can be : The sample space is $\{BB, BG, GB, GG\}$ so that $P = \frac{1}{4}$.

This might also be a way : The sample space is $\{0 \ B, 1 \ B, 2 \ B\}$ so that $P = \frac{1}{3}$.

Are both models correct? Is there a fallacy? I usually see the answers to be $\frac{1}{4}$ so I am confused.

**Edit :** As I have been pointed out, I did mean $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: It should be $\frac34$.  And $0 B, 1 B, $ and $2 B$ are not equally likely

Comment: I suspect the answer you see is $\frac34$ rather than $\frac14$.  Try tossing two coins, several times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's $\frac{3}{4}$.

The mistake in your second example

{0B, 1B, 2B}

is that these 3 possibilities are not equally probable.

I'm assuming that there's an equal probability of a child being a boy or a girl. With that in mind, if a family has 2 children then we have 4 possible outcomes each with equal probability:

GG
GB
BG
BB

Each of these outcomes has a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$. Now we can just count how many of them correspond to the outcome we're interested in, namely that *at least one is a boy*. The answer is clearly that 3 of them correspond to that, so the probability is $\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: May I ask why is that the case? Does that (what you suggest doing) not lead to us assuming when the child is born?

Comment: @dictatemetokcus Assuming that girls and boys are born with equal frequency, iow it's analogous to flipping a "fair" coin, there are 4 possible outcomes of equal likelihood: GG, GB, BG, BB. Since we don't care about the order, there are 2 outcomes out of the 4 that correspond to the family having 1 girl and 1 boy. The other 2 outcomes only come up once out of 4. But you counted these 3 outcomes as equal, when in fact one of them is twice as likely as either of the others. Treat it like 2 coin flips if that makes it easier.

Comment: I still don't understand why we are considering BG and GB differently. When we are considering coins, we are accounting for two different objects and so if we name them, we have two possibilities. In the case of children, how do you name them unless you consider the order of their birth, whence we need to consider they being born on the same time as well.

Comment: Also calculating that order seems difficult, unless we assume one is strictly younger than the other (which is "technically" always the case).

Comment: @dictatemetokcus We don't need to consider the order really. We just need to consider them separate "events". It doesn't matter if they were born at exactly the same time. We just give them different labels. It's really the same as flipping a coin. Does it matter where you flip one coin twice, or two identical coins simultaneously? Either way, you enumerate the possible outcomes in the same way.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus don't get hung up too much on the practicalities of how we would label them. Whether we're talking about 2 children, 2 coin flips, 2 electrons, or whatever, we have to assume that there's _some_ way to distinguish them independently of the characteristic that we're looking for. For example you might flip a coin twice and record results for flip #1 and flip#2. Or you could flip 2 identical coins simultaneously, one in each hand, and record the results as left-coin and right-coin. In a sense it's as if we're saying that the universe recognizes them a distinct events regardless.

Comment: Makes a lot more sense now. This resolves my question. In the $\{B,G\}$ scenario, the Boy could have been a Girl and vice versa and that is a different event. That way, Child 1 and Child 2 can have $2 \times 2$ possibilities. May I ask if there is a case (that is, create a sample space) when their order would not matter (i.e., the cardinality of the space would be $3$)?

Answer (score 1):

There are several other assumptions that must be made.

1. Each child's gender is male or female with probability $1/2$, independent of all other children. That's certainly not quite true: slightly more boys than girls are born, while death rates for males tend to be higher. And I don't know if there is data on how independent they are.
2. Decisions on whether to have another child are independent of the gender of the existing children.  Again, that's certainly not true.